# prohibit adding existing value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a table ingredient w/c consist of(ingredient_id,name). I can perfectly add an ingredient. But i want to add a condition that prohibit on adding existing ingredient. I have the code for that condition but i think it's wrong because the condition didn't work and i can still add an existing ingredient.  please help me

HERE'S MY CODE:

VIEW:

```
 <?php echo form_open('dashboard/uploadIngredients', 'class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"'); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">

                <select required class="form-control" name="ingredient_category">

                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Ingredient Category</option>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <?php foreach($this->products_model->getCategory() as $row): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->category_id ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="5" placeholder="Ingredients (EX. onion, oil, pasta)" required></textarea> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-positive" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save Ingredient</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function uploadIngredients()
{
    foreach(explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients')) as $key => $value) {
        $saveData[] = array('ingredient_id' => null,
                            'name'  => trim($value)
        );  
    }


    $ingredient_id = $this->products_model->saveIngredients($saveData); 

    redirect('dashboard/add_ingredients');
} }
```

MODEL:

```
public function saveIngredients($ingredient_id)
{
    foreach($ingredient_id as $row => $value) {
        $query=$this->db->where('ingredient_id', $value->ingredient_id);
        if($query->num_rows > 0) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
            echo "Ingredient already taken";  
            echo '</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
            $insert_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();  
        }
    }

    return $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: Try focus your question and point out the parts that has to do with _ add a condition that prohibit an ingredient that exist in my table_. Then it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say nothing works? What is the output?

Comment: sorry sir @Michael. i take your advice sir. i edited my question now :)

Comment: the output is that i can still add the existing ingredient sir. like my condition is not working @user3653438

Comment: You're setting ingredient_id to null in your controller, so you'll never find a match. You don't want to compare on the ingredient_id, but on the name instead.

Comment: yes sir that's what i want to condition the name. how can i do that? @DoyleLewis

Comment: still doesn't work sir. where will i var_dump?in the model? @DoyleLewis

Comment: why are you sending `null` in `ingredient_id` ?

Comment: because my ingredient_id is in auto increment @Vinie

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to

```
public function saveIngredients($ingredient_id)
{
    foreach($ingredient_id as $row => $value) {
        $query=$this->db->where('name', $value->name);
        if($query->num_rows > 0) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
            echo "Ingredient already taken";  
            echo '</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('ingredient', $value);
            $insert_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();  
        }
    }

    return $insert_id;
}
```

That should do it. Just changing the $query line.

If that doesn't work, do a var_dump on $value just above that line, so you can see if you need to adjust the value you're targeting.

Comment: still doesn't work sir. where will i var_dump?in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function uploadIngredients()
{
    foreach(explode(',', $this->input->post('ingredients')) as $key => $value) {
        $result = this->products_model->saveIngredients(trim($value)); 
        if($result['status'])
        {
            $ids[]=$result['id'];
        }else{
                  echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
                  echo "Ingredient already taken";  
                  echo '</strong></div>';
        }
    }

    redirect('dashboard/add_ingredients');
} }
```

MODEL:

```
public function saveIngredients($data)
{
        $query=$this->db->where('name', $data);
        if($query->num_rows > 0) {
            return ['status'=>FALSE];
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('ingredient', array('name'=>$data));
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();  
            return ['status'=>TRUE,'id'=>$insert_id];
        }
    }
```

Comment: still dont work sir because i think this issue of mine is about multi-dimensional array :(